# Enter meter unit with Histogram

Tags: plotting, units

I'm looking at the documentation for Histogram and I am trying the example:

```
Histogram[{1 m, 3 m, 2 m, 2 m, 3 m, 2 m, 5 m, 3 m, 2 m, 4 m}, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, TargetUnits -> "Feet"]
```

But my m's are blue and this produces blank output. How do I correctly type in the m's?

Note: I am typing in an example identical to the example in the documentation. If I copy and paste the example from the documentation, it works. But when I type it in myself, it does not work.

From the documentation:

[image]

Comment: The documentation example is using `Quantity` objects as well, as I showed in the answer. To convince yourself of that, select that cell in the documentation, then press CTRL+Shift+I or use the menu Cell -> Convert To -> InputForm to see the structure of the underlying objects.

Comment: So, this is something I should report using feedback?

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks. Turns out this works:  `Histogram[Quantity[{1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 2, 4}, "Meters"], 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, TargetUnits -> "Feet"]`.

Comment: right, yes, that would work: it's pretty much the same thing I did in the answer, i.e. `Quantity[{some list elements}, "Meters"]`. I am not sure what you meant about the feedback though.

Comment: @MarcoB I made a report to Mathematica feedback.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the "Details" section of the [documentation to Histogram](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In order to use the `TargetUnits` options, you therefore need to use `Quantity` objects with the appropriate unit. `Quantity` is `Listable`, so for instance you could use `Quantity[mylist, "Meters"]` as the argument of your `Histogram`.

```
Histogram[
  Quantity[RandomInteger[10, 156], "Meters"],
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, TargetUnits -> "Feet"
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]